# getting the maximum value calculated from 2 columns of data (without helper column)

Tags: excel, vba, function, helper

I have some data, stored in Column A and column B.
For each row, I would like to get the difference between the values in column A and column B.
I.e. cells(1,2) - cells(1,1), so on so forth for the rest of rows.
The second step is to determine if the difference on i row was the max of the preceeding nth rows.
With helper column, I can do it with formula or with code like this.

```
for i = 1 to LR
cells(i,3) = cells(i,2) - cells(i,1)
next i

for i = 1 to LR
if cells(i,3) = .max(range(cells(i-19,3),cells(i,3))) then
cells(i,4) = "MAX"
end if
next i
```

While I don't want to add a helper column, what vba codes can do this?  Can you show me the code for I may not be familiar with the syntax I needed?

Comment: So basically, you want to calculate the largest difference between any value in B and A and return this single value?

Comment: @JvdV hello.  Not actually.  For each pair of data, a difference (di = Bi - Ai) is needed.  I would like to give a flag if di was the greatest among rows i - 19 to i.

Comment: I wonder if I can do it with like function of something similar.

Comment: Have a look at @jamheadart his solution in that case. Notice, you are talking about *difference* here too now...

Comment: Also, why don't you simply "flag" this using conditional formatting anyway?

Comment: Hi JvdV, because I need the flag for later tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what your formula does, without using the helper column. I'm assuming the end goal is to get the word "MAX" written next to the set where the difference peaks

```
Sub PeakDifferences()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim myArr() As Double
Dim subArr(1 To 20) As Double 'change 20 to 19 here if only looking at last 19 numbers

    With ActiveSheet

        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ReDim myArr(1 To lr)

        For i = 1 To lr
            myArr(i) = .Cells(i, 2).value - .Cells(i, 1).value
            For j = LBound(subArr) To UBound(subArr)
                If i - j < 0 Then Exit For
                subArr(j) = myArr(i - j + 1)
            Next
            If myArr(i) = WorksheetFunction.Max(subArr) Then .Cells(i, 3) = "MAX"
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Closest.  But it gave different results from my formula version.  My formula would be (on column C) = B25 - A25, (on column D) =IF(C25=MAX(C6:C25),"MAX","").  May you give your help again and have a look?

Comment: so basically if it's a max against the previous 19 values instead of against all previous values?

Comment: pretty sorry if I didn't made my question clear.  :P

Comment: @JohnLiu I've updated the above code to only look at the max of the last 20 values (C6:C25 is 20 values, not 19) but you can edit the constraints above to 19

Comment: @JohnLiu also note that it checks for where it's EQUALS to the max of the previous n values, not where it's ">=" to the previous n values max

Comment: @jblack, upvote for the helping hand.  But it still not giving the correct flag.  Let me first digest your code.

Comment: @JohnLiu it may be giving different answers from your formula as i had dim'd the arrays as `Long` instead of `Double`. I've updated that part now

Comment: @jblack thank you.  You nailed it.  I caused troubles before since I accidentally swapped Column A and Column B.  Now everything is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you need?

```
Sub e()
Dim i As Long
Dim m As Double
For i = 1 To LR
    If Abs(Cells(i, 1) - Cells(i, 2)) > m Then m = Abs(Cells(i, 1) - Cells(i, 2))
Next i
MsgBox m
End Sub
```

Cycles through the rows and checks if the current maximum difference `m` is outnumbered by the current row difference. It's wrapped in `Abs` to help with any negative values

**BUT** as pointed out by JvdV, this isn't the same thing - my answer is looking for biggest difference, rather than maximum value;

-150 is a bigger difference than 100, but 100 is the max val between -150 and 100.

Comment: Upvoted. But can I make two small remarks. Using `ABS` is not the same as looking for the `MAX` result. Another thing for looping is using arrays just to speed things up.

Comment: I just had a hunch it was biggest difference rather than maximum value, but really I have no idea what his data actually looks like.

Comment: I think my data on column A should always be greater than that on column B at the same row.

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty:

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim lr As Long, mx As Double

With ws
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    mx = .Evaluate(Replace("MAX(B1:BY-A1:AY)", "Y", lr))
End With

End Sub
```

---

Reading comment, you want to return "MAX" to column C where the result of that particular row is been the max value up to that point. Again, quick and dirty:

```
Sub Test2()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim lr As Long, mx As Double

With ws
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("C1").FormulaArray = "=IF(INDEX(B:B,ROW())-INDEX(A:A,ROW())=MAX(B$1:INDEX(B:B,ROW())-A$1:INDEX(A:A,ROW())),""MAX"","""")"
    .Range("C1:C" & lr).FillDown
End With

End Sub
```

A possibly *better* way would be to loop arrays, but other answers cover this approach. I'll stick to `Evaluate` in this example =)

Comment: thank you.  This code gave a "Type mismatch" to me.

Comment: @JohnLiu, see update. Btw, have you refered to the correct Worksheet?

Comment: thanks for the update.  The worksheet reference was okay but still the code does not assign correct flags.  let me digest your code thoroughly and see if it is possible.

Comment: Add a screenshot of your desired result for reference. And yes it's possible =)